# Configure URL on shiny server

Tags: r, shiny

I've been trying to start my shiny server with no success. I followed the instructions at [RStudio site](http://docs.rstudio.com/shiny-server/), but when I check my server status, this is what I get:

```
$ sudo systemctl status shiny-server
● shiny-server.service - ShinyServer
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/shiny-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: deactivating (stop-post) since Mon 2018-04-30 21:16:03 -03; 2s ago
  Process: 17672 ExecStart=/usr/bin/env bash -c exec /opt/shiny-server/bin/shiny-server >> /var/log/shiny-server.log 2>&1 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 17672 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS);         : 17682 (sleep)
   CGroup: /system.slice/shiny-server.service
           └─control
             └─17682 sleep 5

Apr 30 21:16:02 shiny.estatistica.ufrn.br systemd[1]: Started ShinyServer.
Apr 30 21:16:02 shiny.estatistica.ufrn.br systemd[1]: Starting ShinyServer...
```

But [shiny.estatistica.ufrn.br](http://shiny.estatistica.ufrn.br) is not my website! My website is [shiny.estatistica.ccet.ufrn.br/](http://shiny.estatistica.ccet.ufrn.br/) (there is a `ccet` in there). Notice that Apache is alive and running when `ccet` is added to the url.

So, what can I do to start my shiny server? I think there is something to do with the url without `ccet`, but I couldn't figure out how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Shiny Server has nothing to do with Apache. The name `shiny.estatistica.ufrn.br` in the last two lines looks like your server's (machine) name and the missing `ccet` has nothing to do with Shiny Server.

To have http://shiny.estatistica.ccet.ufrn.br/ point to your shiny server, your local IT/network department will be able to help you, as it requires a http request on some sub-level of the ufrn.br-domain to be forwarded to your shiny server.

Answer (score -2):

I would just erase disk and start over, else windup spending far too much "fixing" stuff which isn't how shiny wants to work.